# Occurrence in a file Bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix

I want to count all double occurrence in a file. For example :

```
hellohello (this is counted)
hello (not conted)
```

I tried this code:

```
directory=`find ${dir} -type f`

for file in $directory
do

    o=`egrep 'hello{2,2}' $file`
done
```

but it isnt work and I dont understand why.

Answer (score 1):

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for why `for file in $(find ...)` is bad.

As to the main question though realize that `{2,2}` (and all other modifiers) applies to the most recent atom in the pattern and that a character is an atom by itself so what you have written is

`h` + `e` + `l` + `l` + `o{2,2}`

which isn't what you want.

You want `hello` to be an atom so group is: `(hello){2,2}`.

Comment: Yes ok now it counts the line and the words